# memory leak in nsarray

Tags: iphone, memory-leaks, nsarray

can any one please tell me whats causing the memory leak.
[image]

Data_Parser is an NSObject class. This class parses xml file and the values are stored in a NSMutableArray tList.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're allocating a mutable array in line 46 and assigning it to `ar`:

```
NSMutableArray * ar = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
```

and then in line 48 you're assigning something else to `ar`. That loses the original array you allocated, which you never use or release. (The code doesn't leak if the `for` loop doesn't run due to en empty parser list, but the analyzer is showing you where it will.)

Comment: Got it thanks a ton. I was struggling from an hour with this. Thank you .